# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/products' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Contr

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I'm trying to fetch data created on db ,through postman using axios,i keep getting no access control cors error. I have added the "Moesif Origin & CORS Changer" plugin to my chrome still no solution. I required cors on the server i get the same issue. I dont know what i'm doing wrong.I have read and tried several solutions given here.

**My Client side code(React.JS)**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { popularProducts } from "../data";
import Product from "./Product";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Container = styled.div`
padding: 20px;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
`;

const Products = ({ cat, filter, sort }) => {
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
const getProducts = async () => {
  try {
    const res = axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/products");
    console.log(res);
  } catch (err) {}
 };
 getProducts();
 }, [cat]);
```

**My Backend API (Express)**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const userRoute = require("./routes/user");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const productRoute = require("./routes/product");
const cartRoute = require("./routes/cart");
const orderRoute = require("./routes/order");

const  cors = require("cors");


dotenv.config();

 mongoose
   .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
   .then(() => console.log("DB connection successful"))
   .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

//middleware
app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/products", productRoute);
app.use("/api/carts", cartRoute);
app.use("/api/orders", orderRoute);
app.use(cors());

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
console.log("Backend server is running");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That `app.use(cors())` would work, but you put it after all your API routes, so it's like it's not there. Move it up, below `app.use(express.json())`:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/products", productRoute);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you include the `cors` middleware at the *bottom* of your middleware stack, so it would only ever be reached if none of the routes match, i.e. your 404 errors would have CORS headers but nothing else would:

```js
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/products", productRoute); // This route handles the request
                                        // and ENDS the request processing
app.use("/api/carts", cartRoute);
app.use("/api/orders", orderRoute);
app.use(cors());                        // This is never reached!
```

You need the CORS headers *always*, so you have to put the middleware at the *top* of the stack:

```
app.use(cors());                        // This is executed first, adds the
                                        // headers and continues processing
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/products", productRoute); // This route handles the request
app.use("/api/carts", cartRoute);
app.use("/api/orders", orderRoute);
```

Comment: Thank you. I turned on the Moesif Origin and Core Changer, and everything works just fine . I realised it was never on the whole time. I can see my data now.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issuse but i was able to fix it with following code in my server.js file where the origin:"https://127.0.0.1:5173" is my frontend's url that will be requesting data from the backend

```
const cors = require("cors")
app.options("*", cors())

const corsOptions = {
  origin:"http://127.0.0.1:5173"
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

Answer (score -1):

First, **check the cors version**, if it doesn't work, try to use a **proxy**.

you can use proxy as follow,

in your front-end, **pacakge.json** just add this line of code.

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

And in your Axios.get remove thie http://localhost:5000 and

```
   axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/products");
```

Instead, do it like this

```
    const res = axios.get("/api/products");
```

**And if both doesn't work, then try to install and import body-parser on your server-side.**

```
installtion:
npm i body-parser

import:
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a file called: setupProxy.js within your src folder in client.
Install [http-setup-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware)

Add this to setupProxy.js:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware')
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'http://localhost:5000',
            changeOrigin: true,
        }),
    )
}
```

Finally, restart your application.